# Apache Logs - X-Forwarded-for together with Virtualhost not logging

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, logs, apache-virtualhost, xforwarding

I'm using Apache/2.4.27

Within the VirtualHost I'm forwarding the remote client IP header from the Loadbalancer
with:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
```

Which is needed by the application served by that Virtualhost.

This is the log format within the main httpd.conf context.

```
LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

When I have the `RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For` listed within the virtualhost, Apache stops writting the remote-client IP into logs.

When I remove it from the VirtualHost, the remote-client IP starts appearing again within the logs.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restore %a to that format if you're going to use mod_remoteip.

In bugzilla, mod_remoteip fills in %a while it
removes from %{X-Forwarded-For}i.  So in a simple case with one
trusted proxy, %a will hold the value used to see in
X-Forwarded-For because of mod_remoteip